how to calculate confidence score for each prediction value in CNN regression problem?
In regression let's say i am doing a prediction using CNN and if i have to answer the confidence value for each prediction what should be the way to calculate the confidence level for each value of prediction in a regression problem? As in classification, you can throw the probability value, but what should be the way to do that for regression? Any help is appreciated
